# Why is Angular Material CSS not showing (only raw text shows up)?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Trying to learn how to build Angular Material projects from scratch, somehow only the raw text from controllers is rendered:

[Here is the HTML of the button on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXQUk.png) and here is the [actual button on web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZwls.png).

I double checked the CSS links are correct. What is the problem then?

Comment: Please provide some code, and also don't forget to add ngMaterial as a dependency for your app

Comment: @waynejohn: Its always a good practice to share code using codepen or jsfiddle, so that people can easily help you on that.

Comment: Did you include `mdMaterial` in your main module?

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you already added angular-material css and js files, I think the problem may be in your main `MyApp` module. Don't forget to inject angular-material in your main module like this:

```
angular
  .module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial']);
```

And try to add this classes to your button: `<md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Primary</md-button>`. If it changes to blue button - everything is OK.

**P.s.**: I also don't see any controllers in your DOM